# How to use mongoose to make changes in two different collections in one nodejs query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

In this application, I am trying to update a field value, if it is successful then I want to save into a log collection, however, not all the data are saved in the log collection, I am not sure if I am doing it the right way, would appreciate if someone could help out.

here is the query :

```
// both models(Log & Inventory are imported)

router.get("/add_product/:id/:num/:quantity/:order", (req, res) => {
  var id = req.params.id;
  var quantity = req.params.quantity;
  var order = req.params.order;
  // console.log('id----', id);
  var num_mod = req.params.num;
  var modified_count = parseInt(num_mod) - parseInt(quantity);
  console.log("num_mod----", num_mod);
  Inventory.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { quantity: parseInt(num_mod) }, { new: true }, function(
    err,
    inventory
  ) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("err", err);
      res.status(500).send(err);
    } else {
      console.log(inventory.name);

      const newLog = new Log({
        name: inventory.name,
        description: inventory.description,
        price: parseInt(inventory.price),
        quantity: parseInt(inventory.quantity),
        modified_quantity: parseInt(modified_count),
        itemDest: order //this is not being saved
      });
      newLog.save(function(err, Log) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        } else {
          console.log("add log success");
          res.send(inventory);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

URL from front end :

```
// order is a string
```

here is the Log schema :

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const LogSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    // _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    description: { type: String, required: true },
    price: { type: Number, required: true },
    quantity: { type: Number, required: true },
    modified_quantity: { type: Number, required: true },
    supplier: String,
    taxable: Boolean,
    itemDest: String
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

// Create model from the schema
const Log = mongoose.model("Log", LogSchema);

// Export model
module.exports = Log;
```

and here is the inventory schema

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

//create Schema
const InventorySchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    // _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    description: { type: String, required: true },
    price: { type: Number, required: true },
    quantity: { type: Number, required: true },
    supplier: String,
    taxable: Boolean
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

// Create model from the schema
const Inventory = mongoose.model("Inventory", InventorySchema);

// Export model
module.exports = Inventory;
```

My issue is with this line `"itemDest: order"` in the query, I intend to save the value of `"order"` extracted from `"req.params.order"` into `"itemDest"` but it doesn't save.

Comment: Do you really send a value for `req.params.order`? What url do you use?

Comment: @SuleymanSah yes Console.log(req.params.order) actually has a string value coming from the front end -----  axios.get("/api/inventory/add_product/" + id + "/" + nums + "/" + parseInt(quantity)+ "/" + order)

Comment: So all the fields are saving into the collection successfully but only itemDest field is empty?

Comment: @SuleymanSah Yes all are saving into the "Log collection" except for itemDest

Comment: Did you really see it in the console when you add `console.log(req.params.order)`

Comment: Yes it shows on the console

Comment: Can you try like this? `itemDest: req.params.order`

Comment: @SuleymanSah  just tried it, still not saving bro

Comment: Can you send a screenshot of the document where itemDest is empty?

Comment: Right after u create the `LogSchema` instance with data `new Log({...})` just check what does this get you `console.info(newLog.get('itemDest'))`?

Comment: @ambianBeing after console.info(newLog.get('itemDest')) I got the value of req.params.order

Comment: @8SINS If that is the case indeed then `.save()` should save the property in the db as well. Did u explicitly check in the database. Also `.save()` accepts the document being inserted as param.. try n check at `console.info(Log)` where u are printing `add log success`

Comment: @ambianBeing Thanks, it works now! I actually deleted the collection and started afresh and it saved